# Community discussion about the Sum of Square Roots problem?

Tags: discussion, original-proofs

I was considering posting a question on some of my thoughts regarding the [Sum of Square Roots](http://maven.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/P33.html) and seeing if the community had any responses or ways to contribute, but I wasn't sure if this was really appropriate to this site.

Would a question an a potential proof technique, even if it's a dead end, for the Sum of Square Roots problem be considered too cranky/too open/not appropriate for this site?

Comment: My personal opinion is that such a discussion is not appropriate on cstheory.stackexchange.com, which is not designed for _discussions_ after all.  But to be fair, different users have different opinions on this.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen [Dick Lipton's latest post](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2011/02/26/polynomials-are-easier-than-integers/) on a new result to appear in Complexity 2011 ?

Comment: I should frequent his blog more.  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

Since the site is designed as a Q&A site, I guess it is OK if the question is formulated that a clear single answer exists. As long as the question is in the scope of research-level theoretical computer science, it is appropriate to the site.

However, some of the questions are harder to be answered than others, and the correctness of a specific proof technique may be hard for one to response. Hope that you can find a proper way to state your question, and get good answers here!